# Powerpoint pictures in Latex

Tags: graphics, conversion, powerpoint

I am currently inserting pictures I drew in powerpoint into my Latex file as PNG, however they are fairly blurry. As far as I can understand creating PDFs is will yield a much better resolution. However the problem with this is that all my drawings does not fill out a slide and as I have over 30 it will take ages to crop them adequately. Does anyone know of any way to save individual pictures as pdf?

Many thanks!

Comment: My suggestion would be to make a decision: Are you interested in quality or just transferring the content to LaTeX? If it's the former, then [download Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) and use it's [Potrace](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Potrace) library to trace a bitmap and turn it onto a vector format (SVG). Then save that as a PDF and incorporated it as you need. If it's the latter, then you're stuck with manually cropping the images, as there's no obvious way of cropping a rasterized image (PNG) to certain boundaries.

Comment: Okay thanks, what I will do is create a powerpoint for each picture and then make the design so it fits perfectly.

Comment: You can crop them when including them with `\includegraphics`, but this will not necessarily save you time unless you know the bounding box you need to crop to. If you have to do it by trial-and-error, it is not going to be worth the trouble. Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Werner having tried to trace PNGs in Inkscape recently I don't share your optimism. In my case shading (gradient fills) threw off the algorithm and the huge svg wasn't recoverable to a sensible state. Circles are also problematic, ending up as Bezier approximations, different for identical input. (so much detail to help the OP decide whether it's worth a try)

Comment: I would recommend drawing the pictures in [tikz](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). It's documentation contains some very good examples for different use cases starting at page 28. tikz is a very useful LaTeX package and learning it is totally worth it's time.

Comment: @ChrisH: Of course. If the underlying graphic is extremely complex then you're better off spending the time cropping the original layout to preserve what's there. The current answers all assume some form of blank background to isolate the graphic (another simplification that might not be part of the OP's setup).

Comment: @Werner my case superficially looked simple (the shaded items were on a pure white background) In the end I used the PNG but upscaled in GIMP in one case, and redrew from scratch in the other.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming each image is on a separate slide, you can do the following:

1. Make the Master slide completely blank (no logo, background, etc.)
2. Remove titles from the slides (unless you want them).
3. Export the document as PDF. It's easiest if you put it in a folder of its own.
4. Use [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi) to extract the pages as individual PDF files:

   - `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.5.jar PDFSplit -split 1 YourFile.pdf`
   - This will create a bunch of files `YourFile-1.pdf`, `YourFile-2.pdf`, etc.
5. Use `pdfcrop` (part of TeX Live) to crop the files to their natural size:

   - `for f in YourFile-*.pdf; do pdfcrop $f; done`

This will create new files named `YourFile-1-crop.pdf`, `YourFile-2-crop.pdf`, etc.  These can then be inserted with `\includegraphics` and will not be fuzzy.

If you're using Windows, you're on your own with respect to automating step 5; I've just used `bash` syntax which should work fine on Mac and Linux.

Comment: Pdftk provides another tool for steps 4 and 5 on Windows as well as Linux etc .

Answer (score 3):

Only two steps if you have Adobe Acrobat Pro. After saving your PowerPoint as PDF (assume Images.pdf), open it in Adobe Acrobat Pro and do the following:

1. Under `Tools` click `Pages` and select `Crop`, then double-click on the page and the crop window will appear, choose `Remove White Margins` and `OK`.
2. Again, under `Tools` click `Pages` and now select `Split Document`, a window will appear, specify `Max pages: 1` for the `Number of pages` option and `OK`.

Now you are done! You will have in the same folder `Images_Part1.pdf, Images_Part2.pdf, ..., Images_Part30.pdf` which you can directly include in your LaTeX document.

Here are the steps pictorially:

[image]

and

[image]

then,

[image]

and

[image]