# Improve quality of Windows illustration \includegraphics especially Powerpoint

Tags: diagrams, includegraphics

I have been doing a powerpoint illustration and saved it as a `png` image type. I then included the graphics, by using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]
        {Logo/GICSillustration.png}}
\end{figure}
```

However, when converting the document to pdf, the result is quite ... horrendous. Is there any way to increase the quality? I figured saving it as a `png` file was better, because the illustration contains text. The illustration looks like this:

[image]

I sort of know that using tikz is an option, however, I have no experience in creating illustrations in this tool - only plots.

Comment: png is the wrong format, try to save as pdf.

Comment: [Powerpoint pictures in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364343/134144)  might be interesting.

Comment: It is my opinion that Microsoft goes out of its way to dumb down file exports outside of the Microsoft family as a means to "encourage" you to stay with a complete Microsoft solution.  In cases like this, I just get a large version of the desired image on the screen and use screen capture (CTL-SHFT-PRTSCN) to extract the image.  It will lose any vector-graphics properties it might have had, but at least the pixels you get will be (hopefully) at a decent resolution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "looks horrendous"? I usually do not have issues with PNGS if the resolution is high enough.

Comment: In any case, any loss of resolution comes from the PNG itself.  PDF stores the original PNG image with no conversion, unless your PDF viewer is doing something nasty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some for loops you can actually draw it yourself

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\sffamily % Easier to read; you may remove it if you want
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=mybox]
\path (0,6.9) coordinate (1-a-l) -- (1,5.1) coordinate (1-b-l)
    foreach \i [count=\j] in {2,...,5} {coordinate[pos=\j*10/9] (\i-a-l)}
    foreach \i [count=\j] in {2,...,5} {coordinate[pos=\j*10/9+1] (\i-b-l)};
\path (0,6.9) coordinate (1-a-r) -- (-1,5.1) coordinate (1-b-r)
    foreach \i [count=\j] in {2,...,5} {coordinate[pos=\j*10/9] (\i-a-r)}
    foreach \i [count=\j] in {2,...,5} {coordinate[pos=\j*10/9+1] (\i-b-r)};
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {2,...,5} 
    \draw[blue] (\j-a-l) -- (\j-b-l) (\j-a-r) -- (\j-b-r)
                (\j-a-l) -- (\j-a-r) (\j-b-l) -- (\j-b-r);
\foreach \i/\ins in {0/Sub-industry,%
                     2/Industry,%
                     4/Industry Group,%
                     5.7/Sector} \node[font=\small] at (0,\i) {\ins};
\foreach \i/\ins/\num in {0/Brewers/30201010,
                          2/Beverages/302010,
                          4/{Food, beverage \& tobacco}/3020,
                          6/Consumer staples/30} {
    \node[draw=blue,minimum height=.8cm,minimum width=5cm] at (8,\i) {\ins};
    \node[draw=blue,minimum height=.8cm,minimum width=3cm] (x) at (13.5,\i) {\num};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\dig{8-\i}
    \path (x.south) node[below,font=\small] {\dig-digit};
}
\end{scope}
\draw ([yshift=4pt]mybox.north west) -- ([yshift=4pt]mybox.north east);
\path (0,7.5) node {Classification level}
      (8,7.5) node {GICS example}
      (13.5,7.5) node {GICS code};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Too long for amended comment. 
I have not tested this except for exporting RTF from WordPad as high quality EMF thus as I finish writing NOTE that **you may not need to edit the registry** IF you simply use higher quality vector & font EMF export as described towards the end :-)

Exporting Powerpoint or other Office graphic materials is not a TeX issue as such. However there are many requests such as this one as to how to get good quality import for TeX \includegraphics from Windows applications.

I was wrong in thinking Office exports were not the natural default of 96 dpi for .png (one preferred raster image format) They are the default 96 dpi which was historically used for screen rendering output.

I will summarise here the [Microsoft page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/change-export-resolution-of-powerpoint-slide) for changing PowerPoint output resolution in case the link should vanish. For other applications skip to the end.

### PowerPoint upscaling

This task is not for the faint hearted since it involves a registry edit and if you have not done this in the past for other reasons, it is best to discuss details with someone who has.

Locate the following registry subkey, depending on the version of PowerPoint that you're using: The linked page gives exact version specifics, experienced registry hackers only need to know `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\ version \PowerPoint\Options`

Click the Options subkey, point to New on the Edit menu, and then click DWORD Value.
Type ExportBitmapResolution, and then press Enter.
Ensure ExportBitmapResolution is selected, and then click Modify on the Edit menu.
In the Edit DWORD Value dialog box, click Decimal.
In the Value data box, type the value of the resolution that you want such as 300.

Warnings DO NOT set higher than 300 also if your slides are odd shapes 300 may not work so consider 200 as "safer" for unusual ratios.

In PowerPoint, open the slide that you want to export, on the `File` menu, click `Save As`, in the `Save as` type box, select one of the following picture raster formats:

•PNG Portable Network Graphics Format (.png)

### Powerpoint and other applications

For High Quality **vector and font** output you could use either of

•Windows Metafile (.wmf)
•Enhanced Windows Metafile (.emf)

However they need 3rd party conversion, ideally EMF to EPS for TeX import.

A neat [How to Convert PowerPoint Pictures for Use in LaTeX](https://www.cs.bu.edu/~reyzin/pictips.html) suggests using the standalone [LyX Metafile to EPS Converter](https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/MetafileToEPSConverter)

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will have to remember that in the future. I was not aware of 3rd party conversions, I'll definitely look into that.